# access Web API from windows web service

Tags: windows-services, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Windows service to run maintenance tasks on our customer's servers which returns results to a web service running in our headquarters.

I ran into the Web API as a new and simple alternative to build intuitive web services over HTTP.
So the question is whether or not it's possible to host a Web API web service in IIS 7 at our HQ which is accessed from several remote windows services to return result sets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, and there is [specific guidance on how to do this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) provided by asp.net.

In principle, create your web api project and then from the client do:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mywebapi.mycompany.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var message = new MaintenanceResult { result = resultstatus, server = "servername" };
response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/maintenanceresults", message).Result;
// now check for success, and response appropriately
```